Odd question marks in start of misc reference
I'm using a template I have never before used (here) and for some reason the @misc entry type adds several question marks "????" to the reference when it appears in the bibliography as shown below. I can't seem to get rid of them. (I've tried using @online instead, modifying the title = ..., but with no success...)

Here is the actual reference I used:
@misc{WinNT,   
  title = {{MS Windows NT} Kernel Description},   
  howpublished = {\url{http://web.archive.org/web/20080207010024/http://www.808multimedia.com/winnt/kernel.htm}}, 
  note = {Accessed: 2010-09-30} 
}

Any ideas? I've never encountered this before with other templates.

Please provide minimal example using that setup such that we know exactly what you are doing.

Check the bibtex log file. The bst the setup is using is complaing about two missing pieces of data: year and author. So the ??? comes from the missing author. Note that it is the bst that decides what is required or not.

When I try, those question marks only occur in case the year is missing. The author is not needed. But I am not sure, why this is the case.

If you use an author-date citation system, the year is obviously mandatory.
